# slider event not firing windows 8.1 and windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I am building a simple media player using mediaelement in windows 8.1 .
everything is working fine(play ,pause,player progress).
I am using a timer to show the progess of media in slider.
Problem is there is no event for dragging the thumb of slider.
I have tried manipulationsompleted,Dragenter,Pointerpressed events.
None of the events are firing.
Could you please tell em how can I control the position of mediaelment by using slider thumb dragging.

Thanks..

Comment: What else description do you want..Have already written what I tried..And a developer will automatically get to know what i want to acieve

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve states `When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem.` You have not included **any** code.